# Easiest way to find transfer function of a lossless ladder filter after we finish design?

Tags: rf, filter, passive-filter, band-pass

I have completed my lossless ladder bandpass filter design, but I don't know how to find the transfer function of the resulting circuit without going through the slow and rigorous process of getting resistances of capacitors, inductors, and resistors in the S-domain and working backwards from the end of the circuit until I have an equation relating the output to the input and then solving for Vout/Vin. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you find the values required to implement a particular transfer function or power loss ratio. At least that is the usual approach of the insertion loss method.

Comment: So you have created a ladder topology with parts values WITHOUT knowing the realized transfer function in advance? Very uncommon.

Comment: There is a method invented by FOSTER which shows how such a ladder structure can be described in form of "continued fraction" (the denominator contains a fraction with a denominator which agian contains.....)

Comment: Hence, my recommendation: Goggle for "Foster Partial Fraction"

Comment: One useful tool is [Sapwin](http://cirlab.det.unifi.it/SapWin4/) wherein you can just draw your circuit and it spits out analyses such as transfer functions, pole-zero maps and other plots. These can also be exported to matlab.

Comment: If you didn't start with a transfer function, then what were your inputs to the design process?  And since there seems to be ambiguity, what do you want as a "transfer function" -- are you looking for a detailed Bode plot, a ratio of two giant polynomials in \$s\$, a list of poles and zeros, or what?

Comment: I don't know why you expect this to be an easy process but, if all you want is a click-of-the-mouse approach then search for Elsie, or Qucs, or similar programs that offer LC synthesis. Otherwise you will have to follow the same design process engineers have, all this time.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do a system identification on the circuit. The way that this is done is either providing a step input or a sine sweep (you could also provide an impulse but this probably wouldn't work as well). If you recorded the input and the output (with an oscilloscope) you can feed this into a system identification algorithm and it can find the transfer function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you clearly stated that you had already completed the design, and only need "to determine the transfer function after the design process has finished", I suggest you use Spice, free from TI (called TINA) and linear Tech (called LTspice). Spice will get you the transfer function from your already designed filter.
I suggest you change the first line of your question since it implies you are looking for how to design the filter, but the second line clears up that you are only looking for getting the transfer function from the already designed filter.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you please, in a step-by-step process, explain how can I get the transfer function from LTSpice? Please do not refer me to another site, but state the steps explicitly here.

Comment: The term "transfer function" can mean many things. To some it is an equation, to others a frequency and phase graph, to others a set of S21 parameters. Which are you looking for?

Comment: To  get the Laplace transfer function, a function of ‘s’ like in a textbook, you can use a symbolic algebra program and evaluate the continued fraction. This is the way I have done it. You can use Maple, Mathematica, the symbolic toolbox of Matlab, probably several other programs.  If you are just trying to validate your design, you can use   LTSpice and look at the frequency response graph, but it will not give you the Laplace transfer function.